# persisting related entities in a form symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I want to ask about the possibility of persisting two entities when submitting a form. Is that possible?

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($a);
        $em->persist($b);
        $em->flush();
```

knowing that I have commun fields between the two entities. Actually the fields are generated because of the many to one relation between the two entities. Moreover, I will get some fields added to the second entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's ok to persist two entities, but check first your entities relations, for examples if A has a `oneToMany` relation with B, You'll then have a `addB()` method within `A` entity.

Persisting related entities in this specific use case is as simple as adding `cascade={"persist"}` on your relation and persist `A`.

If you've some specific simple logic you want to add to `B` before saving both `A` with its `B` related elements, you can put this logic in `addB()` so that each time a `B` element is added to your `A` entity, you'll get the change (set the right status, date, ...etc) you want.